# determining the windows type based on the serial number

Tags: windows-vista

If I have my windows vista serial number, how can I know which version is it for (x86, x64, basic, etc).

Also, Can I download for free that windows version and use my serial to authenticate ? I have the serial on the back of my laptop.

Comment: Is there a difference between x86 and x64 keys? For Windows 7 at least, there isn't any.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no legit way to download the Vista disks to do an install. If you can find someone else with the OEM disks, you might do an install that way.

Technically (by the license) this is NOT legit (OEM versions are only supposed to be re-installed via OEM-provided disks), but I don't think you can really be prosecuted for having the thing that came with the system on the system.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Windows that shipped with your laptop is an OEM version of windows. An OEM serial would not work with a version of Windows you'll get from elsewhere (which would be a *Retail* version).

Comment: oke, it is an OEM, but how can i know which one? x64, x86, version?

Comment: Not necessarily, someone might buy an OEM computer together with an higher Windows license, since the end solution sometimes is still cheaper.