# Windows 7: Can I use my 64 bit serial / activation on 32 bit version of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-activation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

My new computer shipped with a 64 bit version of Windows 7 but I want to install a 32 bit version of it (I have the 64 bit DVD). I also have a 32bit DVD which I bought a copy of for my laptop. Can I install the 32 bit Windows on my new computer and use the 64bit serial to activate it or would I have to purchase a new 32 bit Windows OS?

Comment: Related - mentions that serial key used is the same http://superuser.com/questions/127096/determining-the-windows-type-based-on-the-serial-number

Comment: I'm curious at to why you need 32-bit Windows, some specific program or device driver that only works on Win32?

Comment: yea im writing a program for that PC specifically which doesn't install on a 64 bit system. I really tried recompiling the program for x64 for it doesn't just work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, OEM keys are only good for their respective 32-bit or 64-bit versions.

If you had the retail product, you can use the serial number for either.

Comment: it is an OEM key damn they should at least let you downgrade!

Comment: -1 Keys are not specific to platform or language.

Answer (score 3):

When I bought Windows 7 I got both the 64-bit and 32-bit version in the box. And just one serial number. So I think it might work.

But why would you want to use 32-bit instead of 64?

Answer (score 1):

MSDNAA serials work on both 32 and 64 bit versions even if they are for the other-bit version. I guess that applies to the non-MSDNAA keys, too.